# Unable to use toplevelAwait in my next js application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-import

Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iiq65.png)

My next.config.js looks like this. I am trying to use await import like this :

let styles = await import('path') and then I am getting this error from Next.js

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
  eslint: {
    dirs: ["."],
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
  poweredByHeader: false,
  trailingSlash: true,
  basePath: "",
  // The starter code load resources from `public` folder with `router.basePath` in React components.
  // So, the source code is "basePath-ready".
  // You can remove `basePath` if you don't need it.
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental:{
    topLevelAwait: true,
  },
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    // enable top-level-await experiment
    if (!isServer) {
      config.experiments = { topLevelAwait: true };
    }
    return config;
  }
});

I have updated the tsconfig module to ES2022.
```

Comment: What happens if you add `{ ...config.experiments, topLevelAwait: true }` to the `config.experiments` ?